# Is it possible with Firebase Authentication to have a single user across more that one tenant?

Tags: firebase-authentication, multi-tenant, google-iam, google-identity

We are trying to implement a multi-tenancy solution with Firebase. What we want to understand is if it is possible to have a single user that is registered on more that one tenant, so the login flow for that user will be something like this:

1. User INITIALLY signs in with email and password
2. User THEN chooses what tenant to use
3. User THEN accesses the web app

Is this something that can be achieved with Firebase Auth with Identity Platform or must we implement this manually (e.g. not using tenants but putting all the users inside Auth and then, maybe, store the information in something like Cloud Firestore)?

In order to give a concrete example, let's assume that we have 3 available tenants, named

- T-A
- T-B
- T-C

And 2 users named

- U-A
- U-B

`U-A` can access to every tenant, while `U-B` can only see `T-A` and `T-B`. In my head

1. `U-A` logs in with username and password WITHOUT SPECIFYING THE TENANT
2. `U-A` has a dropdown presented where he can choose the tenant from the list (`T-A`, `T-B`, `T-C`)
3. `U-A` chooses `T-B`
4. `U-A` sees `T-B`'s data
5. After a while `U-A` accesses the dropdown and changes from `T-B` to `T-A`
6. `U-A` now sees data from `T-A`
7. Note that all those passages are done **without logging out**

`U-B` does the same passaged but cannot choose `T-C`, because that tenant is not associated to him. He will choose one from `T-A` or `T-B`.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Linking multi-tenant user credentials](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication#linking_multi-tenant_user_credentials) ? With this you can link other types of credentials to an existing multi-tenant user

Comment: no: this is about how to link different providers. What I want to do is to have a user signed in without knowing the tenant and then choosing his tenant ONCE LOGGED. So in my head tenants are groups under users.

For example we have tenants TA, TB and TC and users UA and UB. UA logs in and then can see from a dropdown TA, TB, while UB logs in and can see TA, TB and TC. Based on their choice, I show data of the selected tenant, but this happens AFTER the login process, not before, so I can switch tenant without logging out. Putting this as detail in the question

Comment: Hi did my posted answer help ? If so then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible with Firebase Authentication to have a single user across more that one tenant?

Yes it is possible to have a single user across more that one tenant. For this you will have to Upgrade to Firebase Auth with Identity Platform to access this feature.

But you have to store the info of which type of user can select which tenant in Firestore DB.

> 2. `U-A` has a dropdown presented where he can choose the tenant from the list (T-A, T-B, T-C)

For this you can retrieve the list of available tenants from the [Selecting a tenant](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart?hl=en&authuser=0#selecting_a_tenant) then you can store the selected tenant information (e.g., tenant ID) in a user-specific database, such as Firestore. This allows you to associate the user with the chosen tenant.

> 4. `U-A` sees `T-B's` data

When a user logs in, use their `user.uid` to find their tenant information stored in Firestore as shown above. Use this information to show the user's tenant's data.

> 5. After a while `U-A` accesses the dropdown and changes from `T-B` to `T-A`
>    6. `U-A` now sees data from `T-A`

If the user wants to switch to a different tenant, update the tenant information in the Firestore database. So users can see the selected tenant specific data.

This complex system is just the top view of implementation. This will also need some security rules to get along with the access level.

Reference :

- [**Set up multi-tenancy**](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart?hl=en&authuser=0)
- [**Authenticating with multi-tenancy**](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication?hl=en&authuser=0)